# How do I find the product of numbers in a string(python)

Tags: python, sorting

As you can probably understand I am pretty new to coding and I came across this issue.I want to take user input of 5 numbers separated with "," and to find the product of the max and the min.My code was many iteration of something like that

```py
x=input()

z=x.split(',')

z.sort()
k=int(z[0])*int(z[4])

print(k)
```

but I can not make it to work properly.With input 4,3,5,10,6
it gives me 60 as a result.I tried printing my list and it is not sorted.What do I miss?

Comment: Because you're sorting strings. Convert to integers first before sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to just use `min()` and `max()`. This might be useful if the list of numbers is particularly large:

```py
x = input()

z = [int(val) for val in x.split(',')]

k = min(z) * max(z)

print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I really appreciate you took the time to write that. I had tried the min max method coming from matlab it made sense but I did not int() before creating the list and I think that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the numbers to `int` before sorting. You can use `map` or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that, like so:

```
x = input()
z = [int(i) for i in x.split(',')]
z.sort()
k = z[0] * z[-1]
print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and especially the link. It actually makes sense now.